# If A and B are two logical variables under what circumstances, or conditions on A and B, happens that: A B = A + B

Tags: boolean-logic

If A and B are two logical variables under what circumstances, or conditions on A and B, happens
that:

A B = A + B

Comment: I'm afraid this may not count as a "programming question" (maybe a math question?), it's somewhat related to programming perhaps.. Anyway you can just make the truth tables and see where they match up.

Comment: There are four cases. Try them all.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is gnasher729's, from the comments. Here is a truth table with columns for both expressions:

```
A    B    AB    A+B
T    T    T     T
T    F    F     T
F    T    F     T
F    F    F     F
```

We see AB = A+B for the cases (A, B) in {(T, T), (F, F)}. A simpler way of saying this is that AB = A+B iff A = B.